# unknown top level operator: $geoNear

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am having an error when I try to hit a query in MongoDB.

**unknown top level operator: $geoNear**

This is my query :

```
db.getCollection('placelistings').find({
  $geoNear: {
    includeLocs: "loc",
    distanceField: "distance",
    near: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [74.7043392, 29.9701485]
    },
    maxDistance: 100000,
    spherical: true,
    query: {
      $and: [
        {
          'availablity_detail.on_days': { '$in': ["saturday"] },
          'availablity_detail.daily_schedule.start_time': { $lte: '09:00' },
          'availablity_detail.daily_schedule.end_time': { $gte: '11:00' }
        },
        { '$and': [
          { 'price_detail.price.per_month_status': false },
          { 'price_detail.flat_price.per_month_status' : false }
        ] }
      ]
    }
  }    
})
```

Please help me resolve this issue. I am new to MongoDB.

Comment: `$geoNear` is a MongoDB aggregation pipeline stage, see docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/index.html). Consequently, you need to use the `collection.aggregaete()` method not `collection.find()`. Try updating your query to be something like this: `db.getCollection('placelistings').aggregate([ { $geoNear: { <geo-near optoins> } } ])`

Comment: For performance reasons you may put the `query` conditions at the beginning in a `$match` stage.